# How to give ripple action to a sprite image

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Am  using this coe o show ripple action for my image

```
  CCSprite * ghost = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ghost.png"];
    [ghost setPosition:ccp(500,600)]; 

    CCRipple3D* ripple = [CCRipple3D actionWithPosition:ghost.position radius:ghost.contentSize.width  waves:4 amplitude:20 grid:ccg(40,40) duration:5.0];


    repeatt = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: ripple];
    [ghost runAction:repeatt ];

    [self addChild:ghost];
```

it creates a ripple action for my image,but i need to move this image through a fixed path..means ,it need to move through x axis( 0 )to x(500) then after getting x (500) it need to start from x(0) repetdly.but without removing the ripple action.

how to do this
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two methods and then
use `[self runMyAction:sprite];`

```
- (void)moveActionComplete:(CCSprite*)sprite{
    sprite.position = ccp(0,600);
    [self runMyAction:sprite];
}

- (void)runMyAction:(CCSprite*)sprite{
    CCMoveTo *moveAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:30 position:ccp(500, 600)];
    CCCallFuncN *callbcak = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(moveActionComplete:)];
    CCSequence *action = [CCSequence actions:moveAction, callbcak, nil];
    [sprite runAction:action];
}
```

Also your ripple duration is very slow that's why it seems that it isn't working.
increase your move duration time then you will see when it's moving slowly and ripple effect is visible.
**Play with duration**

Comment: yes i had done that,but when i add this code,the image stopped ripple animation,,and also i want to move the sprite image fom this to 500 x,then automatically need to start agaimn

Comment: sorry i fogot to ad the code [ghost runAction: [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:20 position:ccp(5000,0)]];